# How can I randomly select an item from a list in pinescript?

Tags: arrays, random, pine-script, symbols

I'm new in coding, so...

How can we randomly select an item from a list in PineScript?

I want to randomly generate symbols for the security function

I have a list of symbols like BINANCE:BTCUSDT, BINANCE:ETHUSDT, BINANCE:ATOMUSDT etc

What I need to do to convert it to the array, and generate a random value from it, and put this value to the security function (I suppose when I will reload the page I will get a new randomly generated plot with a new symbol each time)

what I have right now

```
var symbols = array.new_string(5)

array.set(symbols, 0, "BINANCE:BTCUSDT")
array.set(symbols, 1, 'BINANCE:ETHUSDT')
array.set(symbols, 2, 'BINANCE:ATOMUSDT')
array.set(symbols, 3, 'BINANCE:SOLUSDT')
array.set(symbols, 4, 'BINANCE:AXSUSDT')

 
sec = request.security(str.tostring(array.get(symbols,0)), 'D', close)
plot(sec)
```

but it does not work

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done as the compiler needs to know the symbol to be used in the security call at the time of compilation. Any method to generate a random value would result in a series variable for the symbol that can't be passed to the security call.